# Table of contents with hyperlinks by using hyperref: ok in overleaf, ko in texmaker

Tags: packages, overleaf, texmaker, hyperlink

I tried to use the package hyperref to insert hyperlinks in my ToC; it works in overleaf, but it doesn't work in Texmaker (I got a white page with the title index).

How can I fix it in Texmaker?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Immagini/} }
\usepackage{physics}
% mi serve per eliminare il Warning: reference eq: undefined e serve per inserire le note sotto la tabella tnote[]
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
%\usepackage{pgfplots} e \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15} servono per inserire grafici
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}    % 1.18 è l'ultima versione
\usepackage{color} %funziona anche senza
% serve per inserire le note di una tabella alla fine della pagina
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
% serve per inserire il titolo della tabella
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
% serve per poter numerare le singole equazioni in un sistema di equazioni
\usepackage{empheq}
% serve per usare simbolo di cancellazione nella semplificazione
\usepackage{cancel}
% serve per scrivere elenco puntato con lettere al posto dei numeri
\usepackage{enumitem}
% serve per dividere le parole in sillabe correttamente quando si va a capo
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
% serve per andare a capo anche quando il testo è sottolineato
\usepackage{soul}
% serve (forse insieme a graphicx) per aggiungere freccia e testo/equazione sopra segno uguale =
\usepackage{mathtools}
% serve per plottare freccia grande, vuota, ruotata (vedi file: quadrato con frecce)
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
% serve per disegnare retta perpendicolare ad un'altra (vedi file: cerchio e frecce)
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% serve per inserire più immagini in un'unica figure insieme a \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}  % o \usepackage{subfigure}
% serve per scrivere la L di Laplace $\mathscr{L}$
\usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
% serve per inserire due o più volte il numero di una stessa footnote, ossia per riferire ad una stessa nota più parti del testo
\usepackage{savefnmark}
% serve per: (1) evitare che i numeri delle equazioni numerate vadano a finire su un'altra riga quando l'equazione è troppo lunga (scrivi \bigskip subito dopo aver scritto il comando \end per chiudere equazione o sistema di equazioni); (2) impostare i margini della pagina
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,
            top=1.25cm,
            right=1cm,
            bottom=1.25cm,
            bindingoffset=0.5cm,
            marginparwidth=15mm
            ]{geometry}
% serve per poter usare l'istruzione \setlength{\droptitle}{-10em} la quale, scritta prima dell'istruzione \title{}, permette di spostare il titolo in alto
\usepackage{titling}
% serve insieme a \begin{figure}[H] ad imporre che un testo stia sotto una figura (a volte LaTeX inserisce il testo sopra una figura anche se lo si è scritto sotto la figura stessa)
\usepackage{float}
% serve per indentare righe (es. Oss: scrivo testo in modo che non vada sotto Oss:). Serve anche per posizionare un'immagine (figura) esattamente in uno specifico posto della pagina
\usepackage{enumitem}
% serve insieme all'istruzione che segue per poter utilizzare lettere greche nell'elenco puntato
\usepackage{moreenum}
% serve per inserire il simbolo ° nell'elenco di numeri ordinali
\usepackage{textcomp}
% serve per scrivere simbolo 'ristretto a' (o 'valutato in')
\usepackage{array, delarray}
% titlesec e setcounter servono per creare paragrafo (sezione) di livello più profondo al secondo livello rappresentato da subsubsection. In document devi usare \paragraph{}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % 4 se voglio terzo livello di profondità del paragrafo (sezione), cioè subsubsubsection
% tcolorbox serve per scrivere testo, equazioni dentro un box
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% fdsymbol serve per i simboli fiori, picche, quadri
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
% fixmath serve per scrivere in grassetto caratteri in mathbb (es. \pmb{\mathbb{E}}); notare che serve racchiudere tutto tra \pmb{}
\usepackage{fixmath}
%\globalcounter* NON FUNZIONA nel REPORT
% mwe serve per creare i minimal working example (es figure e testo di prova), include anche il packake lipsum
\usepackage{mwe}
% \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} serve per allineare figura (immagine) a sinistra o a destra
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
% \usepackage{circledsteps} serve per cerchiare testo
\usepackage{circledsteps}
% \usepackage{mhchem} serve per scrivere equazioni chimiche (formule chimiche)
\usepackage{mhchem}
%
\usepackage{hyperref}


%-----------------------------------------------------
% serve per scrivere codice C
\usepackage{xcolor}         % serve anche per scrivere simboli colorati (es simbolo implica colorato); per cambiare la gamma di colori a disposizione usa o l'opzione [dvipsnames] o [svgnames] (es \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}). Serve anche per definire un colore specificando i valori RGB (es. \definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{0, 127, 255} ATTENZIONE a non scrivere rgb minuscolo)
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{mGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mGray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mPurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backgroundColour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{CStyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backgroundColour},   
    commentstyle=\color{mGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mGray},
    stringstyle=\color{mPurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    language=C
}
%-----------------------------------------------------


\makeatletter
    \setlength\@fptop{0\p@} %Attenzione: sostituisci i due punti con la chiocciola
\makeatother
%Le 3 righe sopra scritte servono per posizionare un'immagine in alto (piuttosto che al centro) quando questa occupa da sola una pagina

\newenvironment{sistema}%
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{•{}l•{}}}%
{\end{array}\right.}
%Le ultime tre righe righe servono per inserire un sistema di equazioni sulla stessa riga su cui c'è un'equazione

\newenvironment{sistemax}
   {\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
    \left\lbrace \begin{array}{RCL}}
   {\end{array} \right.}
%Questo è meglio di sistema perchè permette di allineare equazioni del sistema che segue un'equazione sulla stessa riga

\newcommand\myeq{\stackrel{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{\textcolor{violet}{*}}}}{=}}
%serve per aggiungere testo sopra segno uguale =

\newcommand{\equparrow}[1][1]{\stackrel{\text{\scalebox{1}[1]{$\uparrow$}}}{=}}
\newcommand{\equparrowx}[2][1]{\stackrel{\mathclap{2}}{\equparrow[1]}}
%Serve per aggiungere freccia e testo/equazione sopra segno uguale =

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
%serve per inserire una footnote non numerata

\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}1\hspace{2em}}}
% serve per creare box intorno ad un sistema di equazioni

\newsavebox{\overlongequation}
\newenvironment{dontbotheriftheequationisoverlong}
 {\begin{displaymath}\begin{lrbox}{\overlongequation}$\displaystyle}
 {$\end{lrbox}\makebox[0pt]{\usebox{\overlongequation}}\end{displaymath}}
 % Serve per scrivere un'equazione matematica centrata che sfrutti tutto lo spazio da sx a dx (=no margini)

\newenvironment{oss}
 {\begin{itemize}[label=Oss:,leftmargin=*]\item}
 {\end{itemize}} %serve per indentare righe (es. Oss: scrivo testo in modo che non vada sotto Oss:)
 
% Le due righe sotto servono per scrivere simboli funzione ceil e floor (funziona anche se c'è frazione) 
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}        % utilizzo: \ceil*{x}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}     % utilizzo: \floor*{x}


\title{
\textbf{Modelli Umani ed Animali in Biorobotica} \\
\large Romano
}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle  %serve per stampare il titolo ed eventualmente altro

% \tableofcontents serve per scrivere (inserire) automaticamente l'indice (la tabella dei contenuti) in un REPORT
% il comando \pagenumbering{roman} PRIMA di \tableofcontents, ed i comandi \cleardoublepage e \pagenumbering{arabic} DOPO \tableofcontents servono per far sì che le pagine della tabella dei contenuti siano numerate con numeri romani (i, ii, iii ...), e le altre pagine con numeri arabi (1, 2, 3)
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduzione al Regno Animale ed alla Nascita della Bionica}
%
%
\section{Introduzione}
Il corso di modelli umani ed animali in biorobotica è organizzato in modo tale da fornire informazioni:
\begin{enumerate}
% \setcounter{enumi}{4} % specifica numero del primo punto. Es: se scrivi 4 il primo punto parte da 5
\item sui sistemi artificiali ingegnerizzati, sui sistemi naturali (o realistici?!);
%
%
\item su aspetti di zoologia che possono essere utili per un ingegnere per progettare artefatti naturali.
%
%
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: have you run latex enough times to generate the table of contents?

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle thank you very much for your hint. After 2 runs, it works very good!